# WCF Operation Serialization Collection Error

Tags: wcf, serialization, dto

I'm returning a collection of DTO objects from a WCF operation.

I get the following error on the service (this only happens occasionally)

Error: Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.

Stack Trace:

```
at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowInvalidOperationException(ExceptionResource resource)
at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.Enumerator.MoveNextRare()
at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.Enumerator.MoveNext()
at WriteArrayOfDeviceDTOToXml(XmlWriterDelegator , Object ,    XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext , CollectionDataContract )
at System.Runtime.Serialization.CollectionDataContract.WriteXmlValue(XmlWriterDelegator    xmlWriter, Object obj, XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext context)
at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext.InternalSerialize(XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, Boolean isDeclaredType, Boolean writeXsiType, Int32 declaredTypeID, RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle)at   System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext.InternalSerializeReference(XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, Boolean isDeclaredType, Boolean writeXsiType, Int32 declaredTypeID, RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle)at WritePositionServerStatisticsDTOToXml(XmlWriterDelegator , Object , XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext , ClassDataContract )
```

The operation code:

```
    public List<PositionServerDTO> GetPositionServers()
    {
        try
        {
            List<PositionServerDTO> list = new List<PositionServerDTO>();
            foreach (PositionServer posServer in dataStore.PositionServerList.ToList())
            {
                posServer.Statistics.CompileStatistics();
                list.Add(Mapper.Map<PositionServer, PositionServerDTO>(posServer));
            }
            return list;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            dataStore.Log.Error("There was an error returning all Position Servers", ex);
            CustomException customerEx = new CustomException("There was an error returning all the Position Servers", 170, ex.Message, ex, "Position Service" , AMSLog.AlphaPositionService);
            throw new FaultException<CustomException>(customerEx, new FaultReason(customerEx.ErrorMessage), new FaultCode("170"));
        }
    }
```

The weird thing - the error appears to be occurring during the serialization of the DTO objects collection, and not in the actual body of the operation. I know this because the exception is not logged as documented in the catch statement.

I've never seen this happen when debugging but I can see the exception as part of the diagnostics trace set up against the production server (yeah, I know), using the SvcTraceViewer.

Anybody got any ideas what's going on here?

Comment: This is an interesting and important problem. What is datastore? Is it an ORM database context? Also what instancing mode are u using?

Comment: The datastore is a singleton that returns a list of PositionServer objects. Not using an ORM and the service context is Per-Session. Ta.

Answer (score 0):

OK, here is your problem:

You are implementing your own XMlSerialization (since I can see `WriteArrayOfDeviceDTOToXml` in the trace) and during the iteration, you are making changes to the list. Obviously I do not have the code but this is what I can see based on your trace.

So I would like inside `WriteArrayOfDeviceDTOToXml` and look for places where I am changing the list.

Alternatively, `WriteArrayOfDeviceDTOToXml` uses a shared resource perhaps for caching and updates it while using it. Without seeing the code, that is all I can say.

---

### UPDATE

OK, if you have not written a seralizer, then it seems that the object you are serializing (`List<PositionServerDTO>`) has other resources which seem to be shared. In fact based on the name, it seems it has `an array of devices` and since your dataStore is a singleton, you are hitting synchronization issues. So the snippet of the code you posted is not where issue is happening. Does `PositionServerDTO` has a list of `DeviceDTO`?

Based on the information given it is all I can say.

Comment: Thanks for having a look. I'm definitely not using my own serialization, I'm letting WCF serialize the object collection for me. I admit though, seeing the WriteArrayOfDeviceDTOToXml was interesting, I presume it uses reflection as part of it's serialization process (?). The method is certainly not one of mine (though the object DeviceDTO most definitely is). Cheers.

Comment: Indeed - the PositionServerDTO contains an array list of DeviceDTO. I've taken this array out of the PositionServerDTO and the error no longer occurs. I'm still uneasy about the process though - like I say the problem was occurring after the method had completed, somewhere in the serialization process performed by the WCF service.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem.

WCF automatic generate that serialization code for you, using your object names throught reflection.

I am studying a solution, my next step is implement my contract surrogate to execute a ToList() in my cache list rewriting this property before pass to serialize without change cache

I hope it helps you, if you have a better solution please post it.

Regards,

Jefferson